# Google analytics application name?

Tags: .net, google-analytics-api, gdata

I'm trying to access google analytics through their .net api.

But connecting requires me to enter the applicaton name.

As described in this article here: http://www.singhvikash.in/2012/08/google-analytics-api-with-net-how-to.html

Specifically here:

```
 AnalyticsService GAService = new AnalyticsService("VikTest-GA-App"); // Application Name
 AccountQuery GAQuery = new AccountQuery();

 //Pass Google account credentials
 GAService.setUserCredentials(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
```

The only parameter in the `AnalyticsService` constructor is the application name.

I can't figure out what the application name is.

Comment: There's a note at the bottom of the article: `Please note this article was created using Google Analytics API version 2.3. As per Google Analytics Notification this feed has been shutdown.`

Comment: I read that note.  That's in reference to the specific data feed that they used to get the data. Which is `/feed/default`.  It's not at all related to the constructor.

Comment: Then it sounds like they left out a step. Go to the [Google Console](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api?#register_project) and create your project (app). Make sure to turn on the Analytics service for your app. Put your app name in new AnalyticsService("VikTest-GA-App");

Comment: @jk so actually project name is app name?

Comment: @Dejel As far as I know, yes. It is what I have done.